# Fix Function Undefined Variable Not Working

Tags: php, function, variables, undefined

So i have a function that I am running all variables through so that it returns "" if the variable is not set. It looks like this:

```
function ck($str){
if(!isset($str) || empty($str)){
    $str = "";
} else {
    $str = $str;
}
return $str;
}
```

I have a call on my page:

```
echo ck($var);
```

No where on my page is $var defined. This should return a blank string and avoid throwing an error - right???

instead, i am still getting undefined variable error. Can some please explain to me why my function isn't working. Thanks.

Comment: Because by passing `$var` to `ch()`, you are _using_ it.  But it hasn't been set.  And you can't use something that hasn't been set.

Answer (score -1):

$var is not defined.  If you want the function to return an empty string you will need to set the parameter to a default value...

```
function ck($str = ''){
    if(!isset($str) || empty($str)){
        $str = "";
    } else {
        $str = $str;
    } 
    return $str;
}

echo ck();
```